# JS - splitting array from output of method

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am very new to JS and am trying to learn to remove the commas from an array i.e. (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window))

When I try to run the split I keep getting "Uncaught TypeError: myVar.split is not a function"

```js
//my array
myVar = (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window));
document.writeln(myVar)

//to remove commas
var newVar = myVar.split(',');
document.writeln(newVar);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8ywq0dt3/1

Hoping someone can help a novice out....

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Arrays don't have commas, nor do they have a `split()` method. If you mean you want to format the array as a string without commas, you probably want `myVar.join("some delimiter that's not a comma")`. See [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: Thanks @Phil that seemed to work... I think I am confused however, so the commas in the output aren't in the array, they are just a to make it more readable to humans?

Comment: All JS objects have a `toString()` method that is invoked when you try to use them in a string context. The behaviour of [Array.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString#description) is well documented